# How do you pick "x" number of unique numbers from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, random

I need to pick out "x" number of non-repeating, random numbers out of a list. For example:

```
all_data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15]
```

How do I pick out a list like `[2, 11, 15]` and not `[3, 8, 8]`?

Comment: Or [9,9,9,9...] : http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Answer (score 150, accepted):

That's exactly what [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) does.

```
>>> random.sample(range(1, 16), 3)
[11, 10, 2]
```

**Edit**: I'm almost certain this is not what you asked, but I was pushed to include this comment: If the population you want to take samples from contains duplicates, you have to remove them first:

```
population = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
population = list(set(population))
samples = random.sample(population, 3)
```

Comment: No, not quite: "Members of the population need not be hashable or unique. If the population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible selection in the sample."

Comment: @delnan: While it would be possible that the original list contains dups, this simply does not seem to be what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thank you a bunch, you solved my problem. My list did contain duplicates. thank you again

Comment: An elegant answer to a simple but important problem.

Comment: random.sample(some_set, 3) is deprecated. Change your set to list for example by unpacking the set and then use random.sample on it. samples = random.sample([*set(population_list)], 3) will work.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this:

```
all_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
from random import shuffle
shuffle(all_data)
res = all_data[:3]# or any other number of items
```

OR:

```
from random import sample
number_of_items = 4
sample(all_data, number_of_items)
```

If all_data could contains duplicate entries than modify your code to remove duplicates first and then use shuffle or sample:

```
all_data = list(set(all_data))
shuffle(all_data)
res = all_data[:3]# or any other number of items
```

Comment: This could still yield repeated values

Comment: Which one sample could yield duplicates?

Comment: The problem is that you are using the list `all_data`, which could contain duplicates. Thus, a `random.choice` from `all_data` or `random.shuffle(all_data)[:n]` could contain duplicate values. Therefore, the proper way to eliminate this issue is to use a `set` of `all_data`

Comment: I know this, thank you, i create my sample using given information and there is no info that there could duplicate entries in all_data, that is why i suppose that author know about set, anyway i have modified my code, thank you for notifying me about week place of mine

Answer (score 9):

Others have suggested that you use `random.sample`. While this is a valid suggestion, there is one subtlety that everyone has ignored:

> If the population contains repeats, 
>   then each occurrence is a possible
>   selection in the sample.

Thus, you need to turn your list into a set, to avoid repeated values:

```
import random
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
random.sample(set(L), x) # where x is the number of samples that you want
```

Comment: `random.choice()` expects a sequence.  Maybe you should test your code before posting.  (BTW, not my downvote.)

Comment: Noted. I realized that just after I posted the code and have changed it in the subsequent edit

Answer (score 2):

Another way, of course with all the solutions you have to be sure that there are at least 3 unique values in the original list.

```
all_data = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,14,15,15]
choices = []
while len(choices) < 3:
    selection = random.choice(all_data)
    if selection not in choices:
        choices.append(selection)
print choices
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also generate a list of random choices, using `itertools.combinations` and `random.shuffle`.

```
all_data = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,14,15,15]

# Remove duplicates
unique_data = set(all_data)

# Generate a list of combinations of three elements
list_of_three = list(itertools.combinations(unique_data, 3))

# Shuffle the list of combinations of three elements
random.shuffle(list_of_three)
```

Output:

```
[(2, 5, 15), (11, 13, 15), (3, 10, 15), (1, 6, 9), (1, 7, 8), ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
fruits_in_store = ['apple','mango','orange','pineapple','fig','grapes','guava','litchi','almond'] 
print('items available in store :')
print(fruits_in_store)
my_cart = []
for i in range(4):
    #selecting a random index
    temp = int(random.random()*len(fruits_in_store))
    # adding element at random index to new list
    my_cart.append(fruits_in_store[temp])
    # removing the add element from original list
    fruits_in_store.pop(temp)  
print('items successfully added to cart:')
print(my_cart)
```

Output:

```
items available in store :
['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'pineapple', 'fig', 'grapes', 'guava', 'litchi', 'almond']
items successfully added to cart:
['orange', 'pineapple', 'mango', 'almond']
```

Answer (score -1):

If the data being repeated implies that we are more likely to draw that particular data, we can't turn it into a set right away (since we would loose that information by doing so). For this, we need to pick samples one by one and verify the size of the set that we generate has reached x (the number of samples that we want). Something like:

```
data=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
x=3
res=set()
while(len(res)<x):
    res.add(np.random.choice(data))
print(res)
```

some outputs :

```
{3, 4, 5}
{3, 5, 6}
{0, 4, 5}
{2, 4, 5}
```

As we can see 4 or 5 appear more frequently (I know 4 examples is not good enough statistics).