# selecting random str from a list without repetition python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Good day I have some problem regarding selecting a random string from my list I am currently developing a small guessing word game.

```
list = ["Mango", "Apple", "Banana", "Blueberries", "Watermelon"]
```

I want to select randomly string from this list without repeating the string. Example- When my code run it select randomly a string suppose that the string is **Apple** but two or three times later it's select second time **Apple** string but I want which string was selected then not repeat another time the string.

**Actually I want which string is selected one time then the string not select**

Comment: How is `python-requests` tag relevant for this question?

Comment: duplicate look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494508/how-do-you-pick-x-number-of-unique-numbers-from-a-list-in-python with `random.sample(range(1, 16), 3)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you pick "x" number of unique numbers from a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494508/how-do-you-pick-x-number-of-unique-numbers-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values from the list without repeating them, you should use random.sample. An example of this could be, it is the following code:

```
import random
list = ["Mango", "Apple", "Banana", "Blueberries", "Watermelon"]
print("".join([str(list[x] + '\n') for x in random.sample(range(0, len(list)), len(list))]))
```